# Dictionary or Vocabulary?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

Could you help me, please? In our country EL students have got special copy-books where they write new English words down (not in alphabetical order). How is it correct to call such a copy-book in English: a dictionary or a vocabulary?

Comment: It would be called a vocabulary list most of the time.

Comment: So, may I ask my students 'Open your vocabularies, please?'

Comment: Dictionaries are comprehensive, officially, widely-distributed reference works. Personal, ad-hoc lists of words would more likely be called "vocabularies" (or simply "word lists"), as @RK01 says.

Comment: I would not say, "Open your vocabularies" since a vocabulary is a body of recognized words.  Your written list of vocabulary words is fundamentally a *list* or a *book* or a *journal* etc. which can be modified with the adjective *vocabulary* to scope its use.

Comment: Jim, and what about 'Open your vocabulary books/lists, please'?

Comment: That sounds perfect.

Comment: Like [hundreds of others](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22vocabulary+crib+sheet%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl) I'd call it a ***vocabulary crib sheet***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My gut feeling is that a vocabulary book or glossary isn’t necessarily the same as a vocabulary crib sheet. A crib sheet to me implies some kind of nefarious activity, like writing notes on a small pad and using it during an exam though you’re not allowed. Calling notepads where students simply write new vocabulary in order to learn it better during class ‘crib sheets’ seems to be putting a bit of a negative spin on the thing to me.

Comment: @Janus: Check out my link. I don't see any overwhelming preponderance of negative references to exam cheating there.